# Deleting Main Stack Exchange Account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to completely delete everything I have with Stack Exchange, but I can only delete the accounts on specific communities. The main stackexchange.com account doesn't seem to have an option to delete it. I just see this: [image: 1488]

(No, the "Update profile info" doesn't show any more options)

Comment: What precisely does delete look like to you? If you edit that, we can see if it’s different than the many posts on removing attrition and the standard account deletion process.